# Microsoft Planner "We're not ready for you yet" error

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-planner

Error URL: https://tasks.office.com/EN-US/Home/Error?correlationId=af20d461-efc8-4b7a-ba3e-d1e89e80d221&errorId=TenantUnavailable

[Pic of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxCYg.png)

Any time I try to access Planner, I get the above. And I'm still getting emails from open tasks.

Answer (score 1):

AS Planner now is available for Office 365 Enterprise E1–E5, Business Essentials, Premium and Education subscription plans, I’d like you confirm if you enter Planner via https://tasks.office.com and https://portal.office.com/account#subscriptions.

For me, I can visit Microsoft Planner online. However I can't create new plan because plan and Office 365 Group creation are disabled by our organization's global admin.

[image]

When I visited the URL mentioned in your question, I got the same error message. Was it switched to the page when you failed to sign in? It shows a "Tenant Unavailable" error.
I have noticed that the error will occur when Office 365 Planner is rolling out. You may need to wait for the result.

Hope the information was helpful.